# How to create databases dynamically with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a web application where the users will have the ability to create their own databases within the application. I’ve already referred to multi-tenant database concepts, I want to create the same application using multi-tenant database, I’m finding it difficult to implement the same inside my application.

Example:

```
MyAPP -> User A-> Database A
MyAPP-> User B-> Database B
```

My requirement is to create an application for multiple users to create their own databases within the application dynamically (according to their own specifications).

Can someone provide me with codes to implement the above. 
I'm using Netbeans, hibernate, jpa, ejb.

Comment: That's probably too broad for SO. You'd need to dynamically create entity classes, the database and tables, a datasource for Hibernate to use etc. Have a look at the Hibernate docs, e.g. `https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html` (it might be the wrong version though so look for the documentation that fits yours) - the discriminator approach (same db, same schema) seems to be the best suited for dynamic tenants.

Comment: Thank you. I need to know how to do it inside my application.I do not know how to do in code.I reffered but could not get a good idea about it.

Comment: Do you really need a different database for each client? you will need to create the connection dynamically. I used this approach in the past, I had a lot of performance problems, then I decided to have just one database and keeping the client id to each table. (it's also a multi-tenant approach)

Comment: @RafaelZeffa Can you tell me how did you do it in the past?